# How can I add a stroke property to a drawn element?

Tags: javascript, svg, svg.js

I have a function that draws circles on my svg element:

```
function drawCircle( pElem, pX, pY)
{
    pElem.circle( 7 ).fill( '#00FF00' ).move( pX, pY );
} //drawCircle
```

But I want to add a black stroke to the drawn element like this:

```
function drawCircle( pElem, pX, pY)
{
    pElem.circle( 7 ).fill( '#00FF00' ).move( pX, pY ).style.stroke = 'black'; //tried this but it didn't work

} //drawCircle
```

How can I do this? 
(Note: I'm using svg.js library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [API doc](https://svgjs.com/docs/2.7/manipulating) mentions a total of five possibilities:

```
.stroke('#000') // seems hex notation is expected
.attr('stroke', 'black')
.attr({stroke: 'black'})
.style('stroke', 'black')
.style({stroke: 'black'})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is exactly that what i was searching for

Comment: I searched for it, in google and in the documentation but i dind't found it so thats why o posted here (im not english fluent so that makes harder to me to find). I dont intend to put questions to be downvoted.